# cn1 - get file path to image for share()

Tags: share, codenameone

I'm trying to use the `share()` method, including an image, but I'm having trouble supplying the proper path to the image.  Where should I put the image file, and what is the path (putting in the default package and trying "jar:///myimage.png" didn't work), and why is this not documented clearly?

Answer (score 3):

image can be stored in storage which is following path for window
C:\Users\userName.cn1

and the image can be read by using following codes

```
InputStream is =  Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("tizbn.JPG");
EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());
```

Loading image from default folder

```
Image i =EncodedImage.create("/tizbn.png");
```

Loading image From Theme

```
EncodedImage current = (EncodedImage)  fetchResourceFile().getImage("tizbn.png");
```

Comment: Ok, I see there was a major misunderstanding here.  I have an image I want to package with the app (the app logo), and want it to be shared with the share text.  I don't know how to refer to the path of the file that's packaged in the app.

Comment: you can inbuilt in theme as well as default folder of app and the image can be readed as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The share API works with https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html[FileSystemStorage] and not with https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html[Storage].

You need to save the file into a file system path which is always an absolute path, we recommend using the app home to store files. There is a sample in the [developer guide section on the ShareButton](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_sharebutton) covering this:

```
Form hi = new Form("ShareButton");
ShareButton sb = new ShareButton();
sb.setText("Share Screenshot");
hi.add(sb);

Image screenshot = Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(), hi.getHeight());
hi.revalidate();
hi.setVisible(true);
hi.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);

String imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "screenshot.png";
try(OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile)) {
    ImageIO.getImageIO().save(screenshot, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
}
sb.setImageToShare(imageFile, "image/png");
```

Comment: There's no way to pull the file from the jar?

Comment: You can get a file from the JAR but you need to save it to FileSystem to use it in the share code. Place the file in the root of the src directory and open it with `Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream("/myFileName");` then instead of using Save and the whole screenshot process just use `Util.copy(inputStream, outputStream);`.